# Cumulocity: Advanced Threshold Alerts

Tags: cumulocity

Our devices will report measurements based on a value that has a target that will vary per site for example:

```
Site A - Measurement X Target Value = 20
Site B - Measurement X Target Value = 22
Site C - Measurement X Target Value = 25
```

I would like to be able to trigger alarms when measurements exceed a percentage difference from target.

For example a minor alarm will be triggered at +/- 15% and a critical alarm at +/- 30%

My SO rep is too low to embed an image so [see my awful drawing here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze3HK.jpg)

This is necessary as devices at each site will be calibrated to a different value for the measurement; one threshold doesn't suit all and the alarm thresholds are either side of the target, not just increasing or decreasing values.

How could this be implemented with current functionality?

Would it be considered as a feature for the datapoint/alarms area?

Answer (score 0):

The SmartRule "On measurement threshold create alarm" has exactly this functionality.
If you create a datapoint with yellow and red range and use the SmartRule it will create a minor alarm for measurements in yellow range and critical alarms for measurements in red range.

Comment: No, I don't think it does.


I want to set a target value of 25.
The yellow range should be the range 20 to 30
The red range should be anything below 20 and anything above 30.

This seems not possible with the current UI.

See: http://imgur.com/V7xJicm

Also I would like to be able to create an alert based on a percentage difference from target value. Absolute values are not quite so useful as each site will have a different value. I want to be able to know when a measurement drops by, for example, 25% or 50% from target, for hundreds of sites it will be cumbersome to configure.